# Exponential Plot shows up as linear graph in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, exponential

I'm trying to plot the exponents of 2 vs the 2 to the power of the exponent but I keep getting a linear graph instead of the curve. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
from random import seed
from random import random
import math

tiktok=0


#Desired style
style.use('dark_background')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)


T= open('live_graphText.txt','w+')
T.truncate(0)
T.close()
test = f=open('live_graphText.txt','w+')
for i in range(10): 
    test.write("%d,%d\n"%(i,math.pow(2,i)))
    tiktok = tiktok+i
test.close()
```

In addition I'm trying to use the live graph animation from matplotlib.animation with a file i created. to keep automatically keep adding points to the file but it seems the function isn't even being called. I'm not sure if I just have it called in the wrong place or the function just doesn't make sense

```
#This is not being called
def edit(tik):
    global tiktok
    f=open('live_graphText.txt','a+')
    f.write("%d,%d\n"%(tik,math.pow(2,tik)))
    print("HelloWorld")
    tiktok = tiktok +1
    f.close()


def animate(i):
    #Opening the file to read
    graph_data = open('live_graphText.txt','r').read()
    #Split the lines by \n
    lines=graph_data.split('\n')
    xs =[]
    ys =[]
    for line in lines:
        #This if statement ignores any white space at the end of the file
        if len(line)>1:
            x,y = line.split(',')
            xs.append(x)
            ys.append(y)
    #print(xs)
    #print(ys)

    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs,ys)
```

#The parameters are (Where to plot the function, the function we are plotting, the interval we want to plot in milliseconds)

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,interval=1000)


plt.show()
while tiktok<20:
    edit(tiktok)
print(tiktok)
plt.show()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: P.S. The output image is found where it says "enter image description here"

Comment: As your y-axis is shown in log-scale, an exponential is supposed to look like a perfect straight line.  Set the y-scale to linear if you want to see a curved function.  (The code shown doesn't seem to include plotting functions.) Further, your code `for i in range(10): tiktok = tiktok + i` sums the numbers 0 to 9 making tiktok equal to 45. Therefore the `while tiktok < 20` will never be entered.

Comment: What does the file writing have to do with this graph? can it be removed from the example? In other words, can you simply hard-code example data into a list or array?\